# Is there a mandate for the variable to be of data type "integer" for arithmetic operations "+" and "-"?

Tags: verilog

Following is the code for finding factorial of a number. If I declare "i" as "register", the output (z) remains 1, irrespective of the input. If it is declared as "integer", I get the proper result. Why is it so? Please explain.

```
module Factorial_calc(n, z);
input [5:0] n;
output reg [64:0] z;
reg i;
// integer i;

always @(n)
begin
i=0;
z=1;
 while(i<n)
 begin
 i=i+1;
 z=i*z;
 end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your integer is 32 bits wide and your reg is only one bit wide. Your simulation should not finish for most values of n, let alone produce a result.

HDL is not like any other programming language. Beware that even if your code simulates it does not mean it will work in hardware. In your case it will not synthesize. You value of `n` is undefined at compile time.

Last be not least do NOT use x or z for variables, They are too easily confused with `'x` or `'z`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Suppose "i" is [5:0] reg, I use an "initial" block for initializing "i=n" with the modified logic "while(i>0)" with decrement of "i". The code doesn't give proper result. Why is it so? Can I not initialize "i" to "n" within "initial" block? It works for initialization within "always" block.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do but my feeling is it will not work. For a varaible 'n' you should use a clock and a counter which counts down. It will take n clock cycles to get the result.